# Generate the cdf from the pdf

Tags: probability, density-function

What is the process for generating the cdf from the pdf?
For a simple example:

If I have pdf: $f(x) = 3x^2$

What is it's corresponding cdf, and how do I derive it?

Comment: $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\ f(u)\ du$

Comment: by definition the cdf is just $F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\mathrm dt$

Comment: $$F(x) = \Pr(X\le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(u)\, du.$$

Comment: @zoli win :) :P Hardy third place.

Comment: Note that to use the above you need to be careful about the implicit domain of your PDF, and extend it to be zero elsewhere.

Comment: Upvoting for very kinglike dog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know nothing else about probability density functions, the first thing you should know about them is this: Suppose (lower-case) $f$ is the probability density function for the distribution of a random variable $X$. Then, for every measurable set $A$ in the range of $X,$ we have
$$
\Pr(X\in A) = \int_A f(u)\,du.
$$

And the first thing to know about cumulative probability distribution functions is this: Suppose $F$ is the c.d.f. for the distribution of $X.$ Then
$$
\Pr(X\le x) = F(x).
$$

Combining these two facts, you have
$$
F(x) = \Pr(X\le x) = \int_{(-\infty,\,x]} f(u)\,du = \int_{-\infty}^x f(u)\,du.
$$
(Note that I wrote $(-\infty,x]$ with a round bracket on the left and a square bracket on the right.)